# Automate saveas dialogue for IE9 (vba)

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to download an excel sheet from a website. I have thus far achieved until clicking the download button automatically (web scraping). Now ie9 is popping a save as screen. How do i automate that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try this as it is worked for me on IE9:

[image: For below showed download]

1. Copy file `C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll` file to users Documents i.e `C:\Users\admin\Documents` then add reference `UIAutomationClient` to your macro file.
2. Paste below code in your module:

   ```
       Option Explicit
       Dim ie As InternetExplorer
       Dim h As LongPtr
       Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

   Sub Download()
       Dim o As IUIAutomation
       Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
       Set o = New CUIAutomation
       h = ie.Hwnd
       h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
       If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

       Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
       Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
       Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

       Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
       Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
       Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
       Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
       InvokePattern.Invoke
   End Sub
   ```

Try at your end.

Comment: When i am trying to add refernence to UIAutomationClient it's throwing a error : "Error in loading DLL".

Comment: you have to copy the file `UIAutomationCore.dll` to your document folder.

Comment: `PtrSafe` is not getting recognized. It says *Expected: Sub or Function*

Comment: Caution! If you are foreigner then you should properly change button name instead of "Save" like "Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "열기")"

Comment: How to close window after `If h = 0 Then Exit Sub` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
'This is a working code for vba in excel 2007 to open a file
'But you need to add the "UIAutomationCore.dll" to be copied 
'from "C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll" into the 
'path "C:\Users\admin\Documents"    
'The path where to copy may be different and you can find it when you check on 
'the box for UIAutomationClient - the location is given under it.
'Tools-references

Option Explicit
  Dim ie As InternetExplorer
  Dim h As LONG_PTR
  Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LONG_PTR, ByVal hWnd2 As LONG_PTR, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LONG_PTR


Sub click_open()
  Dim o As IUIAutomation
  Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
  Dim sh
  Dim eachIE

Do

    Set sh = New Shell32.Shell
     For Each eachIE In sh.Windows
         ' Check if this is the desired URL

    ' Here you can use your condition except .html
    ' If you want to use your URL , then put the URL below in the code for condition check.
    ' This code will reassign your IE object with the same reference for navigation and your issue will resolve.
         If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, "<enter your page url>") Then
         Set ie = eachIE
         Exit Do
         End If
     Next eachIE
 Loop

Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = ie.Hwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")


Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I sent the shortcut keys to IE11.

Note: the code will not run as you expect if IE is not the active window on your machine so it won't work while in debug mode. The shortcut keys and how to send them are below.

- Shortcut key:<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- VBA: `Application.SendKeys "%{S}"`