# Wait until OPEN/SAVE/CANCEL mini window appears in the IE browser. FindWindowEx() is Failing on Looping through IE in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download files from the IE browser with Excel VBA. I'm using the following three libraries to drive process in complete automation.

> 1. SHDocVw
> 2. MSHTML
> 3. IUIAutomation

There are three files to download one by one by filling some information on the form of the webpage. Each file has a different file size.

I require a dynamic wait mechanism which keeps my program on hold until OPEN/SAVE/CANCEL mini window appears in the bottom of the IE browser.

[image]

To detect a mini window on the IE browser, I used FindWindowEx Function to call an API to get whether the window has arrived.

Here is the code to perform the dynamic wait.

```
Private Sub WaitTillFrame(ByVal oBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)

    Dim heWnd As LongPtr
    Dim Ret As LongPtr

    Do Until heWnd > 0
        Ret = oBrowser.hWnd
        heWnd = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Above code worked for the first file but when code starts preparation of the second file for download it doesn't wait until the mini window appears.

I have noticed while debugging, Ret Value remains unchanged. Because of that `FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)` thinks the dialogue box has appeared but it has not.

It keeps running, without waiting until the mini window appears. I download the first file and remaining two files are missed.

Here is element of the export button.

```
<button title="Export" class="x7g" style="background-image:url(/xmlpserver/cabo/images/swan/btn-bg1.gif)" onclick="return exportReport('xdoRptForm', '/xmlpserver/ECOM_RDC/MERCHANDISING/SOH_Report/Stock Available For Upload Transfer/Stock Available For Upload Transfer.xdo');" type="button">Export</button>
```

I'm posting my whole module but the code above is the key.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If

Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Public Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE

Public Sub UPL_Reports_Automation()

    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim I As Long
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo EhhError
    Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

    'Login Screen
    TargetFolder = "D:\TestingDownloaing"
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium

    'Navigate to the Login Page
    IE.navigate "http://10.110.10.78:9704/xmlpserver/login.jsp"
    IE.Visible = True

    WaitLa 5

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    'To check if the Login page is there or not ?
    Set D = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("xy")(1)

    'Bypassing the element if the login page is visible.
    If Not D Is Nothing Then
        D.Click
        WaitLa 5
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
        Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    End If

    'Enter Login ID
    Set A = HTMLDoc.getElementById("id")
    A.Value = "merchandiser"

    'Enter Password
    Set B = HTMLDoc.getElementById("passwd")
    B.Value = "merchandiser"

    'Click on Login Button
    Set C = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("submitButtonEnable")(0)
    WaitLa 2
    C.Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'Part 2 Navigate to UPL Page
    IE.navigate "http://10.110.10.78:9704/xmlpserver/ECOM_RDC/MERCHANDISING/SOH_Report/Stock%20Available%20For%20Upload%20Transfer/Stock%20Available%20For%20Upload%20Transfer.xdo"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    WaitLa 5

    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

    'Select Template Format
    Set G = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_xf")
    G.selectedIndex = 1

    FName = vbNullString
    FileName = vbNullString

     'Download Territory wise files
     For I = 1 To 3 Step 1

        Select Case I
            Case 1
                'UAE
                Set F = HTMLDoc.getElementById("terr")
                F.selectedIndex = 9
                IE.document.getElementById("terr").FireEvent ("onchange")
                FName = "UPL-UAE"
                WaitLa 9

            Case 2
                'RIYADH
                Set F = HTMLDoc.getElementById("terr")
                F.selectedIndex = 8
                IE.document.getElementById("terr").FireEvent ("onchange")
                FName = "UPL-KSA-RIYADH"
                WaitLa 9

            Case 3
                'BAHRAIN
                Set F = HTMLDoc.getElementById("terr")
                F.selectedIndex = 1
                IE.document.getElementById("terr").FireEvent ("onchange")
                FName = "UPL-BAH"
                WaitLa 9

        End Select

         'Creating a File Name
         FileName = TargetFolder & "\" & FName & ".txt"

         'Click on Export Button
         Set H = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("x7g")(1)
         H.Click

         Call WaitTillFrame(IE)

         'Automation to Download  File
         Call Download(IE, FileName, True)

    Next I

    IE.Quit

ClosedIt:

    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set A = Nothing
    Set B = Nothing
    Set C = Nothing
    Set D = Nothing
    Set E = Nothing
    Set F = Nothing
    Set G = Nothing
    Set H = Nothing
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

    Exit Sub

EhhError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Last File Downloaded : " & FName, vbCritical, "Error Reporting'"
        Resume ClosedIt
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub WaitTillFrame(ByVal oBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)

    Dim heWnd As LongPtr
    Dim Ret As LongPtr

    Do Until heWnd > 0
        Ret = oBrowser.hWnd
        heWnd = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub  

Sub WaitLa(ByVal Seconds As Byte)
If VBA.Val(Seconds) <= 9 Then
    Call Application.Wait(VBA.Time + VBA.TimeValue("00:00:0" & VBA.Val(Seconds)))
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038165/automate-saveas-dialogue-for-ie9-vba)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, Sir, I went through it earlier and many threads. Actually, if you look at the code, it builds on the same concept. It worked for me on the single download but when I create a loop to download documents one by one by filling the form, the code stops working. I found, the RET value in the first download was 0 but when loop triggers the second download, RET has it's earlier value, so the FindWindowEx captured that value and without getting the save as dialogue, it skips to the third download. and the same happens with the third too. any idea?

Comment: Ret will always have the same value. The value of `heWnd` should change. Put a break on the line `heWnd = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)` and check the value of it realtime

Comment: Also you have an `Export` button? Does it point to a specific download link? If yes then you can also try using `URLDownloadToFile` API

Comment: @SiddharthRout : here is the link of the Page...
http://10.110.10.78:9704/xmlpserver/ECOM_RDC/MERCHANDISING/SOH_Report/Stock%20Available%20For%20Upload%20Transfer/Stock%20Available%20For%20Upload%20Transfer.xdo

Here is the Element of the Export Button 

<button title="Export" class="x7g" style="background-image:url(/xmlpserver/cabo/images/swan/btn-bg1.gif)" onclick="return exportReport('xdoRptForm', '/xmlpserver/ECOM_RDC/MERCHANDISING/SOH_Report/Stock Available For Upload Transfer/Stock Available For Upload Transfer.xdo');" type="button">Export</button>