# VBA code to run another password-ed VBA code

Tags: vba, passwords

I have a VBA macro, developed by a third party, and which is password-protected. When the macro finishes what is is supposed to do, it shows a message box, and to continue beyond that the user needs to click a button. Before the button is clicked, you cannot do anything else .

I need to run that macro on several files. Is there a way to bypass the message box, and just call another instance of the macro, on a different file...?

Comment: Depends on how it was coded.  If all you need to do is click a button, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-filehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-file) may help.

Comment: Sorry, but I get a "page not found when I access the link, and a code which, judging by the URL, is related to ÏE and file downloads. Are you sure you posted the correct link? If so, me being rather a beginner with VBA, I fail to understand how it can help... :(

Comment: Sorry, the URL appears to have pasted twice above. This is the [correct link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-file), and while the question is about an IE dialog, the answer applies to *any* dialog.