# Click on an IE Window without SendKeys or MouseEvent - VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I have to click on **SAVE** in Download Window shown attached.
I want do it using VBA but not using sendkeys or mouseevent.
I wish something smiliar this: [VBA Internet Explorer Automation - How to Select "Open" When Downloading a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-file)

See attached the windows that has the button and the properties from these windows (got using AutoIT) and a resume below:

Download Window: [Download Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lff2k.jpg)
AutoIT Window Properties: [AutoIT Window Properties 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYw7O.jpg)

Window
Title: Windows Internet Explorer
Class: #32770
Position: 1672, 227
Size: 391, 287
Style: 0x96C80284
ExStyle: 0x00010101
Handle: 0x005002D6

Control
Class: Button
Instance: 1
ClassnameNN: Button1
Name: 
Advanced (Class): [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 
Text: &Open
Position: 10, 114
Size: 365, 40
ControlClick Coords: 302, 30
Style: 0x5000200F
ExStyle: 0x00000000
Handle: 0x0048073C

Visible Text
&Open
&Save
Save &as
Cancel

Comment: Can you use IE's DOM explorer to find the element? Perhaps you can just use JavaScript to click the element.

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly with the code below:

```
Sub Download()
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = ie.hwnd
h = FindWindow("#32770", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
```

End Sub