# VBA Internet Explorer Automation - Select “Open” or "Save As" When Downloading a File

Tags: vba

Trying to figure out a way to automate "Open" or "Save As" when opening a file from a companies internal website.  I am using the following script to open the file:

```
Public Sub OpenURL()

Dim myURL As Long
myURL = ShellExecute(0, "Open", "https://bankofamerica.xxxx.com/sso/bankofamerica/respInv.do?xxx)

Call Download

End Sub
```

Once the first part executes, I get the blinking file dialog box at the bottom of the screen (below) so far so good:

[File Dialog Box Prompt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG80F.png)

However, when it calls the sub 'Download' which I stole from 
[VBA Internet Explorer Automation - How to Select "Open" When Downloading a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-file)

```
Option Explicit

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim h As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

Sub Download()
    Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    h = IE.hWnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")

    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

I get the 'Object Variable or With Block variable not set' Error on the following highlighted line (am I missing a Reference?):

[Download Sub Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3sLT.png)

I am okay running in shell or otherwise if there is a better way, just need to figure out how to automate either to 'Save As' or 'Open' in the dialog box.

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so apologies if it's not perfect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)