# VBA continues without waiting for second workbook to open/close

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through a list of csv files from a website which I want to open and extract the data from. The reason I'm using VBA is because the specific files I need to open varies day per day, and those specific file references is available only in an excel view. The second reason is because I've already made a similar scraping application in vba, so I already had half the code.

The end user of the application doesn't need clean or fast code, just that it works, because checking these files manually now is a daily chore of 2 hours per day.

So far I'm already logged into the website where the secondairy files are stored (This website has no API so I'm scraping it) and I'm opening those files by letting the code click the buttons. The code then clicks the export button, which opens the dialog box to

```
open, save (dropdown), cancel
```

I just want to open and extract the data then close, so I'm using the code from [VBA Internet Explorer Automation - How to Select "Open" When Downloading a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400795/vba-internet-explorer-automation-how-to-select-open-when-downloading-a-file) . It feels like my code is bugging on this part...

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim h As LongPtr

Function Download()
    Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    h = ie.Hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If h = 0 Then Exit Function

    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")

    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    InvokePattern.Invoke
End Function
```

before I invoke this function I check the amount of workbooks and make excel wait upto 20 seconds until another workbook is opened. I do that with this code

```
    xnum1 = Application.Workbooks.Count

    Download

    t = Now
    tStop = t + TimeValue("00:00:20") 'Adjust the TimeValue as needed "hh:mm:ss"
    Do Until t = tStop Or Application.Workbooks.Count > xnuml
        DoEvents
        t = Now
    Loop
```

However it seems that even with this wait time, excel doesn't want to open the file during every loop. If I run it step by step, it does open the file, when I let it run on it's own, it doesn't.

After I downloaded the file I export the data to the main file and then close it, using *Application.DisplayAlerts* to ensure no dialog box prevents the closing of the file. But because the code bugs in the download I've had instances where the file opened too late and then it didn't close, and because they all have the same filename I made an extra safegaurd in the main code:

```
    xnum1 = Application.Workbooks.Count
    For y = 1 To xnum1
        If Left(Application.Workbooks(y).Name, 10) = "export.csv" Then
            Application.Workbooks(y).Close
        End If
    Next
```

I can't seem to figure out why excel isn't opening the files properly and then closing them properly... Seems like the code just runs, goes into error mode because the file didn't open in the second run, although no error is given by the code itself even when I step through it.

My gut is telling me that this Download function is where the problem lies, but I can't point out how to fix it...

I've also tried with sendkeys %{O}, the shortkey to click open, but this also didn't open the file. When I manually click alt + O it does open the file...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest not using `Do Until t = tStop` - just in case `DoEvents` takes more than a second. Better to use `Do Until t >= tStop`.. But then again, why wait 20 seconds at all? Surely the other half of the test (`Application.Workbooks.Count > xnuml`) is better - and foolproof?

Comment: The reason why I'm using a timestop is incase the secondairy file never opens, my code will stop. If I don't have that, excel would get stuck in this situation. So this is a safegaurd against unforseen reasons why the file doesnt open. If the file did open, then the program doesn't wait

Comment: Have you investigated using GET / POST requests on an MSXML2 object to emulate sign-in, navigation, download - and with the data responsebody you can save it to txt / csv then open it from disk instead of sending iffy button clicks to an IE instance? I feel like it'd be a lot more reliable and controllable..

Comment: No I have not, nor is it something I've looked into much at all... any resource you could suggest to get deeper into that subject?

Comment: I assume to get MSXML2 to work, there needs to be an web API, which as mentioned there isn't

Comment: Is there a website link you can share?

Comment: Sadly enough no, atleast you need a login to get anywhere. Fyi it's a government website, where I live those are usually crap, like this one without an API.

Comment: I have the same problem, when i step through the file opens. currently i have a loop with doevents until the number of workbooks increases but the new workbook doesnt open while the loop is running... ><